# How should I organize Python source code?

Tags: python, unit-testing, code-organization

I'm getting started with Python (it's high time I give it a shot), and I'm looking for some best practices.

My first project is a queue which runs command-line experiments in multiple threads. I'm starting to get a very long `main.py` file, and I'd like to break it up. In general, I'm looking for: **How do python programmers organize multiple source files?** Is there a particular structure that works for you?

My specific questions include:

1. Should each class be in a separate file?
2. How should I organize unit tests relative to source code?
3. Where should I put doc comments, specifically those for command-line operation?
4. If I use multiple directories, how do I import classes between them?

I can probably draw some of my own conclusions here by trial and error, but I'd rather start from something *good*.

Comment: This will explain a couple of things about organizing your code http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Here is some more useful info from python docs. <br>
http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Answer (score 35):

The [article Eric pointed](https://web.archive.org/web/20190714164001/http://infinitemonkeycorps.net/docs/pph/) to is awesome because it covers details of organising large Python code bases.

If you've landed here from Google and are trying to find out how to split one large source file into multiple, more manageable, files I'll summarise the process briefly.

Assume you currently have everything in a file called `main.py`:

- Create another source file in the same folder (let's call ours `utils.py` for this example)
- Move whatever classes, functions, statements, etc you need from `main.py` into `utils.py`
- In `main.py` add a single line at the top: `import utils`

Conceptually what this does is to create a new module called `utils` in another source file.  You can then import it wherever it's needed.

Comment: Do you happen to remember the article Eric pointed to? I can't seem to find an Eric on this question/answer

Comment: @DrewNoakes: I think it was deleted for being a link-only answer; if only he had summarized the article's main points.

Comment: Unfortunately the article is a dead link now :-(. The latest archived version is here: https://web.archive.org/web/20190714164001/http://infinitemonkeycorps.net/docs/pph/

Answer (score 8):

The way you should organise your code and tests is exactly the same you would for any OO language.

Answers from the way I do it. It may not be right but works for me

1. Depends on how your functionality is split. For my main python app I have 1 file with classes for the entry points and then packages of different bits of functionality
2. I use PyDev for eclipse and organise it like I would for Java.

> ```
> >  Workspace
> >     |
> >     |-Src
> >     |   |-Package1
> >     |   |-Package2
> >     |   |-main.py
> >     |-Test
> >         |-TestPackage1
> >         |-TestPackage2
> ```

3. Use DocString everywhere to keep track of everything
4. After making sure that the relevant `__init__.py` files are in the folders. its just a simple case of `from module import class`

Comment: One caveat, though:  java takes kind of a dictatorial relationship with packages, files and classes.  Sometimes I end up with way more source files than I would really want.  The conventions of some organizations  --  e.g. - avoid (nested) inner classes or "helper" classes lower in the file -- make this worse, beyond the compiler's requirements.   Keep it orderly, and a hierarchy is useful, but try to avoid make-work.