# How to organize Python source code files?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, code-formatting, project-structure, code-structure

I am developing a Python App Engine app, where I want to split the content of a source code file `Models.py` into separate files for each model, but I want to put it all in a folder called Models. The problem is that when I do that, my app can't find the classes anymore. What should I do?

This question is not about MVC [but another question with the same title is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849311/how-should-i-organize-python-source-code).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put an empty `__init__.py` file in the Models directory.

Then, in your app; presumably one level up, you reference modules in the Models directory like this:

```
import Models
```

and do something with it like this:

```
Models.my_model.MyClassName
```

You can also use the `from` keyword like this:

```
from Models import my_model
```

and reference like this:

```
my_model.MyClassName
```

If you only need one method from a module, you could also do this:

```
from Models.my_model import my_method_name
my_method_name()
```

Obligatory link to the [**documentation**](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Comment: I voted this up, with the cavet that module and package names should be lowercase. and that directories with ____init____.py files are packages not modules.

Comment: the problem with splitting classes into different files in Python is that I have to add the module prefix wherever I use it. This is cumbersome and it doesn't happen in C#

Comment: @Jader:  You can avoid having to do this by importing the specific classes you need explicitly with `from module import ClassName`.

Comment: @Adam I got that, the problem is that if I use 10 classes in 10 different modules I will have to write 10 imports

Comment: @Jader Dias, Python modules may contain 0, 1, multiple classes. Modules help to organize them for use and thought, and a given module should have as many classes as make sense. Avoiding import lines is a minor concern. Multiple classes in one module makes sense if and because they are closely-related.

Comment: @Jader: and your point is ... what? You prefer to have automagical pollution of your namespace? If you need do this once in one file it will take you less time to *do it* than to make a comment here. If you find yourself doing this in many places then it's time to understand Python's package mechanism, the use of the __init__.py file (hint: it's not just to be an empty file), and other ways of bringing multiple, disparate functions into scope. See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages for all of the exciting details.

Comment: If you don't want Models to be a package, skip the __init__.py and add the Models directory to sys.path; you should then be able to import the files contained there directly.  Or don't put them all in a subdirectory in the first place; do you really have so many project files that this is necessary?

Comment: @Mike @Peter @Wooble Please keep in mind that I am used to other languages where each file content usually fit one screen and more than one class per file is a major sin

Comment: @Wooble, modifying `sys.path` isn't something you can do in a real program. It makes programs fragile and unportable.

Comment: @Mike Graham: App Engine is a controlled environment.  You don't have to worry much about portability; since the entire set of APIs you'll be using will make it unportable in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

In response to your comment to Adam's answer, regarding having 10 imports for 10 classes, firstly don't forget that there's no need to have one class per module in Python. Modules should be organised by functionality, so you can group related classes in a single file if that makes sense.

If you still wanted to make all the classes importable in one go, you could import them all in the `__init__.py` file itself using the `from submodule import Class` syntax, then just import the containing module - `import mainmodule` and refer to `mainmodule.Class1` etc, or even use `from mainmodule import Class1, Class2, Class3` to import the classes directly into your namespace and refer to them directly.

Answer (score 1):

Adam Bernier provides a good technical description of how packages work. A great description of how to arrange and ship a project is described in http://jcalderone.livejournal.com/39794.html