# Python - organising code and test suite

Tags: python

I am very new to python, coming from a php background and cant figure out the best way to organise my code.

Currently I am working through the project euler exercises to learn python.  I would like to have a directory for my solution to the problem and a directory that mirrors this for tests.

So ideally:

```
Problem
    App
        main.py
    Tests
        maintTest.py
```

Using php this is very easy as i can just require_once the correct file, or amend the `include_path`.

How can this be achieved in python?  Obviously this is a very simplistic example - therefore some advice on how this is approached on a larger scale would also be extremely grateful.

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849311/how-should-i-organize-python-source-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on which test runner you want to use.

**pytest**

I recently learned to like [pytest](http://pytest.org/latest/getting-started.html#our-first-test-run).

It has a section about [how to organize the code](http://pytest.org/latest/goodpractises.html#choosing-a-test-layout-import-rules).

If you can not import your main into the code then you can use the tricks below.

**unittest**

When I use `unittest` I do it like this:

**with import main**

```
Problem
    App
        main.py
    Tests
        test_main.py
```

`test_main.py`

```
import sys
import os
import unittest
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'App'))
import main

# do the tests

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.run()
```

**or with import App.main**

```
Problem
    App
        __init__.py
        main.py
    Tests
        test.py
        test_main.py
```

`test.py`

```
import sys
import os
import unittest
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

`test_main.py`

```
from test import *
import App.main

# do the tests

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.run()
```

Comment: What is __init__.py useful for in this example?

Comment: `__init__.py` is an empty file that makes App a package. This makes `import App` import `App/__init__.py` and you can import `App/main` with `import App.main`

Comment: So python sees any __init__.py files and adds that location to the path?

Comment: No. When you do `import App` Python looks in every directory in `sys.path` for something with the name `App`. If App is a file, it is imported. If App is a directory and has a `__init__.py` then the `__init__.py` is taken.

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dirname'

Comment: fixed that.. it should be os os.path.dirname i guess.

Answer (score 0):

I have always loved [nosetests](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), so here is my solution:

> Problem
>
> ```
> App
>
>     __init__.py
>     main.py
>
> Tests
>
>     __init__.py
>     tests.py
> ```

Then, open the command prompt, CD to `/path/to/Problem` and type:

> nosetests Tests

it will automatically recognize and run the tests. However, read this:

> Any python source file, directory or package that matches the
> testMatch regular expression (by default: (?:^|[b_.-])[Tt]est) will be
> collected as a test (or source for collection of tests).
> [...]
>
> Within a test directory or package, any python source file matching testMatch will be examined for test cases. Within a test module, functions and classes whose names match testMatch and TestCase subclasses with any name will be loaded and executed as tests.

This basically means that your tests (both your files and function/methods/classes) have to begin with the "test" or "Test" word.

More on Nosetests usage here: [Basic Usage](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html).